# Optimize Django Queryset for loop

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

How can I optimize the following queryset?

```
[link.goal for link in self.child_links.all()]
```

I want to get rid of the for loop and hit the database only once.

I've got the following code:

```
class Goal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    progress = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

def calc_progress(self):
    progress = 0
    subgoals = [link.goal for link in self.child_links.all()]
    for subgoal in subgoals:
        progress += subgoal.weight * subgoal.progress
        weight += subgoal.weight
    progress = progress / weight / len(subgoals)
    self.progress = int(progress)


class Link(models.Model):
    parent_goal = models.ForeignKey(Goal, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="child_links")
    goal = models.ForeignKey(Goal, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="parent_links")
    weight = models.SmallIntegerField(default=1)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.parent_goal) + "-->" + str(self.goal)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are already hitting the DB once

Comment: Are you planning to use subgoals somewhere? You can use an aggregate to gather all of the data if I understand properly what you are trying to do...

Comment: I edited the code so that you can see what I'm doing with the subgoals

Comment: @DeepSpace: the database is hit a single time with `self.child_links`. But since `goal` is a `ForeignKey`, resolving the `ForeignKey`, results in the tranditional *N+1* problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to get rid of the for loop and hit the database only once.

Well `goal` is a `ForeignKey`, so that means that this is a tranditional *N+1* problem, you can reduce the load, by using a `.select_related(..)` or `.prefetch_related(..)`:

```
[link.goal for link in self.child_links.select_related('goal').all()]
```

Answer (score 3):

Willem is correct that `select_related()` will reduce your database queries, but what you should really be trying to do is to move your calculations to the database using Django aggregates.

```
from django.db.models import Count, F, Sum


def calc_progress(self):
    agg = (
        self.child_links
        .order_by()
        .annotate(
            progress=F('goal__weight') * F('goal__progress')
        )
        .aggregate(
            progress_sum=Sum('progress'),
            weight_sum=Sum('goal__weight'),
            count=Count('id'),
        )
    )
    progress = agg['progress_sum'] / agg['weight_sum'] / agg['count']
    self.progress = int(progress)
```

This is untested, so some tweaks may be necessary, but the general idea is that these calculations will be more efficient if done in the database, and `select_related()` will no longer be necessary. This function only makes one database query.

You may find this [Django ORM Optimization cheat sheet](http://concisecoder.io/2018/11/04/django-orm-optimization-tips/) I wrote helpful for situations like this.