# django-rest-framework speed-up endpoint with http requests

Tags: python, django, backend

I have an application on DRF and there is an endpoint inside which sends an http requests in the loop for each item.
Endpoint is very slow because of this, any ideas how to speed it up?
example of code

```
class MyView(APIView):
    def get(self, request: Request) -> Response:
        for cat in Cats.objects.all():
            data = CatsInfoService.get_info(cat) # send http request
        return Response({"message": "ok"})
```

Comment: You might consider using a task scheduler for sending the HTTP requests. Something using celery will do the work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using an iterator like this?

```
class MyView(APIView):
    def get(self, request: Request) -> Response:
        for cat in Cats.objects.all().iterator():
            data = CatsInfoService.get_info(cat)
        return Response({"message": "ok"})
```

Also, I think this article could help as well [Optimize Django Queryset for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53693786/optimize-django-queryset-for-loop)